# Fetching checked items in simple list view

Tags: android, android-listview

I have simplelistview(not custom) with simple_list_item_multiple_choice and a button. I want to find out the checkboxes checked by user on click on button. I am using below code:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
       ListView lv = MainActivity.this.getListView();
       SparseBooleanArray selectedItems = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();

       for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
                    int selectedPosition = selectedItems.keyAt(i);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedPosition+": checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
             }  
        });
    }
```

Problem: It shows all items as checked whether it was clicked or not. According to the functionality of `getCheckedItemPositions()`, it is supposed to return only checked checkboxes.

For the time being, i have used `lv.isItemChecked(i)` inside for loop which tell me whether this checkboxes was selected or not. But this way is not correct because if there are 100 items in the list then my loop will run for 100 times.

Please help me out!!

Comment: can you detect change in checked/unchecked state?

Comment: i can find it out with lv.isItemChecked(i) but my question is that why getCheckedItemPositions() is not returning only checked checkboxes?